# Error when trying to rename a table using sp_rename

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table `Logistic.Logistic.DIM_DATE` and I try to rename it using `sp_rename` but I get the following error message :

> No item by the name of 'Logistic.Logistic.DIM_DATE' could be found in the current database

Below is my query :

```
EXEC sp_rename 'Logistic.Logistic.DIM_DATE', 'DIM_DATE'
```

Comment: What is the name of the table itself? (I mean, just the table, without the schema and database name)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Logistic.DIM_DATE

Answer (score 1):

Since the name of the table doesn't follow the SQL Server's [Rules for Regular Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers) (it contains a dot) you must wrap it with either double quotation marks or square brackets:

```
exec sp_rename 'Logistic.[Logistic.DIM_DATE]','DIM_DATE' 

-- Or

exec sp_rename 'Logistic."Logistic.DIM_DATE"','DIM_DATE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below :

```
exec sp_rename '[Logistic].[[Logistic]].[DIM_DATE]]]','DIM_DATE'
```